# Does an infinite dimensional operator $T$ having an eigenvalue of $0$ imply that $T^{-1}$ doesn't exist?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I can't seem to find anywhere a discussion on whether or not the idea of a zero eigenvalue (value in the point spectrum) implies the inverse doesn't exists for an infinite dimensional operator.

We know for a finite operator, this is the case (a 0 eigenvalue means a matrix is not invertible). I am wondering if this same condition (or some other condition on the eigenvalues or spectrum) gives us that the inverse of an infinite dimensional operator doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Having an eigenvalue of $0$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{ker} (T - 0I)$ is non-trivial, which is equivalent to $T$ not being injective. What breaks down is that $0$ not being an eigenvalue only implies $T$ is injective, not that $T^{-1}$ exists, as injectivity and bijectivity are no longer equivalent for linear operators on infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. Is there a condition that will make the operator invertible? I am dealing with this problem particularly, Let $(\lambda_j)$ be a sequence of real numbers with $\lambda_j \neq 1$ for all $j$ and $\lambda_j \rightarrow 1$. Consider $T: \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ defined for $\xi_j \in \ell^2$ by $$T(\xi_j)=(\lambda_j \xi_j)$$ I am trying to find a condition on the $\lambda_j$ so that $T^{-1}$ exists. The $\lambda_j$ are the equivalent of eigenvalues since they are in the point spectrum of T

Comment: Well, the obvious modified condition is that $0$ is not in the spectrum of the operator (by definition). My first potentially useful thought is that you might want to consider $\|I - T\|$, and show that it's strictly less than $1$. Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (I - T)^n$ converges to an inverse of $T$.

Comment: Wouldn't 0 not being in the spectrum not be enough from what you said above? I am confused what you mean by obvious modified condition... I was looking at that proof in my book that uses that sum, I will think about that some more, I am thinking that we need $||T||\geq 1$ for the inverse to not exist. I think that is equivalent to one or more of the  $\lambda_j$ being larger than 1 in norm maybe?

Comment: The spectrum is the set of all scalars $\lambda$ such that $T - \lambda I$ is not invertible. This is larger than the set of eigenvalues: the subset of the spectrum such that $T - \lambda I$ is not injective. So $0$ might be in the spectrum ($T$ is not invertible), but not be an eigenvalue ($T$ is injective). I call the modified condition "obvious" because saying $0$ is not in the spectrum is literally just re-stating the condition that $T$ is not invertible, without hinting at any way forward (except possibly armed with a term to Google).

Comment: The condition $\|T\| \ge 1$ is not necessary (or sufficient). Take the $0$ operator for instance!

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. 0 in the spectrum means non invertible. Thanks. I will think about the condition some more. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I just figured out why you said $||I-T||<1$ because $(I-(I-T))^{-1}$ in that series will give the inverse of $T$ :D